# Python - Passing String as HTML tag

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to pass a SelectField variable to a table using Flask. The variable is being passed as a string and the list is not appearing. 
I need help to pass the SelectField as HTML tag and not as string.

```
## Setting the form
class BanksList(FlaskForm):
    banks_db = banks.query.all()
    bank = []
    i=0
    for ban in banks_db:
        bank.append((i, ban.bank))
        i = i+1

    bank = SelectField('Banks', choices= bank)

## Part of read_statement(filename, bank_name) function to read xls file and convert
## into pandas dataframe

    form = BanksList() #Flask Form
    statement['Account'] = f"""'"{{{form.bank}}}"'""" #setting the column of DB to be SelectField

## Part of the server.py file that uses flask  
    @app.route("/transactions", methods=["GET","POST"])
    @login_required
    def transactions():
        form = BanksList()
        df = read_statement(session['file'],session['selected_bank'])
        return render_template("transactions.html",
                                tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')],
                                titles='',
                                form = form)

## HTML File
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% for table in tables %}
                    {{titles[loop.index]}}
                    {{ table|safe }}
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwqTg.png)